# Проблемы с правами доступа в Camunda

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, docker, camunda

Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь добавить себе проверку прав для пользователей, так как все новые пользователи имеют доступ администратора

Все настраивается через Docker. Build Camunda:

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-7.17.0
COPY production.yml /camunda/configuration/production.yml
```

.yml setup file:

```
camunda.bpm:
  webapp:
    csrf:
      enable-same-site-cookie: true
      same-site-cookie-option: STRICT
    header-security:
      hsts-disabled: false
      content-security-policy-value: base-uri 'self';
        default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
        img-src 'self' data:;
        block-all-mixed-content;
        form-action 'self';
        frame-ancestors 'none';
        object-src 'none';
        sandbox
        allow-forms
        allow-scripts
        allow-same-origin
        allow-popups
authorization:
    enabled: true
    user-id-claim: sub
    administratorGroupName: camunda-admin
    authorizationCheckRevokes: never
  generic-properties:
    properties:
      enable-password-policy: true
   admin-auth:
     enabled: true
     administrator-user-name: admin
     administrator-group-name: admins
```

Проект строится, но авторизация до сих пор не работает, судя по документации, то все эти настройки максимум, что нужно сделать, чтобы он заработал. Кто настраивал авторизацию, подскажите что не так?

Comment: javascript или java?

Comment: Что Java или JavaScript? Проект на котором стоит Camunda написан на JS, если это интересовало вас

Comment: Просто создалось ощущение, что одна из этих меток на вопросе попала на него по ошибке.